# How can I change the formatting of arrays within annotations in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, code-formatting, checkstyle

I have the following code in a Java file within Eclipse:

```
@Annotation({"arg1", "arg2"})
public void method() {
    ...
}
```

I have an issue whereby CheckStyle dislikes that particular formatting and warns that:

```
Whitespace Around: '}' is not preceded with whitespace.
```

However the eclipse formatter will not allow me to add any whitespace and will remove it whenever I format.

If I just wanted to remove the warning then I would have to disable the `Whitespace Around` rule for `}` within CheckStyle, but then it won't warn me when I screw up in other places, so don't want to do that.

The authors of CheckStyle [have added the option I would need](https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/pull/111), by allowing you to *ignore Annotation Array Initialization curlies as it does for Array Initialization outside of annotations.* **However, CheckStyle have not released a new version with the update** and have no roadmap for when they will do so.

In any case, lets say that I agree with CheckStyle and would like a space before the `}`, **how can I configure the formatter with my preference**, or at the least, to not care about this issue?

---

*I am aware of* `@formatter:off`, *I am hoping for a one off solution in the formatter configuration, not something I have to use every time I use an array within an annotation.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your settings under `Preferences` -> `Java` -> `Code Style` -> `Formatter`. Then `Edit`  your active profile and check under `White Space` -> `Arrays` -> `Array initializers`.

There you can tell Eclipse to use `White Space` characters before and after the brackets.
[image]

Comment: I thought I'd checked that, but obviously I hadn't, for some reason I thought Eclipse would have a different configuration for arrays within annotations.